# How can I print the frames per second on my window's title in glut?

Tags: opengl, glut

I tried this:

```
    char window_title[20]; 
    sprintf(window_title, "%f", fps);

    glutCreateWindow(window_title);
```

And isn't updating (remains 0)
I checked fps being updated via printf.

How can I update the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `glutSetWindowTitle` with the fps after you compute it.